# Editing Event on front get an error

Tags: wordpress, civievent

i would like certain wp users to use civi on front page. For certain operations it works:

https://domain.com/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/status

https://domain.com/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fsearch&reset=1

https://domain.com/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fsearch&reset=1

even

https://domain.com/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fmanage%2F

it's ok !

but when i try to edit an event directly (with an ID) like this

https://domain.com/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fmanage%2Fsettings&reset=1&action=update&id=521

the main page load but when the event inner tabs try to load content via ajax it fails..
i always get an error..

I have this problem on local, on stage and on prod servers..

Have anyone ever experienced the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just upgraded to 5.50.2 and WP 6 and it's working now.

I can edit my event on the front-end

https://domain.ccom/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fmanage%2Fsettings&reset=1&action=update&id=521

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit an event using front end url, it should be

https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fmanage%2Fsettings&reset=1&action=update&id=521

Certain tabs/pages require additional admin permission

Comment: "Certain tabs/pages require additional admin permission" .. do you know were these permissions are located ?  Would be cool if as an admin all the civi pages were available on front.